# SQL :Switch/Case in where clause

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to do this in SQL:

```
 where (table1.col1 = table1.col2 
   and  table2.col1 in ('01','02')) or
       (table1.col1 <> table1.col2 
   and  table2.col1 in ('03','04'))
```

I want to know how to do by `Switch/Case`, I want to try(but failed):

```
where table2.col1 in case 
        when table1.col1 = table1.col2 then 
          ('01','02') 
        else 
          ('03','04') 
      end
```

Comment: Stick to AND/OR instead of case.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is specify a condition, based on which part of sql query will be executed.

Using  switch/case, you can specify a condition and based on condition, "then" part will perform some action.

What you are trying to do : "then ('01','02') " doesn't make any sense to SQL. Here in then part, you have to specify action/query which you want to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

What is shown as being attempted in the OP, as an effect for the **CASE *expression***, is improper usage.  The CASE expression effects a *result-expression*, of which ('01','02') is not an expression capable of being evaluated.  However a **values-clause** would be a valid result

The variant of DB2 on which I tested the following WHERE clause gave an error [sqlcode:-811 "result more than one row"] that I did not expect; i.e. for the IN predicate, more than one row should be acceptable.  Perhaps this coding might be valid and functional when used on some other variant\level of DB2?:

```
 where table2.col1 IN (case when table1.col1  = table1.col2
                            then (values('01'), ('02')) end)
    or table2.col1 IN (case when table1.col1 <> table1.col2
                            then (values('03'), ('04')) end)
```

The following WHERE clause did work as I expected; what I inferred to be the effective equivalent of the above WHERE clause employing the CASE expression.  Of course, quite conspicuously, this one does **not** use any CASE logic:

```
 where  table2.col1 in (select c2                             
                        from (values('01'), ('02')) as s (c2) 
                        where  table1.col1  = table1.col2    )
    or  table2.col1 in (select c2                             
                        from (values('03'), ('04')) as s (c2) 
                        where  table1.col1 <> table1.col2    )
```

I am not sure what the goal is with wanting to use the CASE expression, but FWiW, I offer additionally the following, which although quite nearly the same as what is in the OP, may have some value in review.  The WHERE clause uses a **CASE *expression*** to perform the same logic as the WHERE clause from the OP; the first IN predicate ANDed to the second predicate in parentheses is optional, but makes explicit what values are allowed for table2.col1, outside of any OR logic, presuming an increase in the potential for the optimizer to better\sooner recognize that limitation on the data:

```
 where  table2.col1 in ('01', '02', '03', '04')               
   and (    table1.col1 =  case when table2.col1 in ('01','02')
                                then table1.col2 end           
        or  table1.col1 <> case when table2.col1 in ('03','04')
                                then table1.col2 end           
       )
```